# Magento: how to use catalogsearch/query model to find products without images?

Tags: magento, search

This is my code:

```
$catalogSearchModel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($q);
$catalogSearchModelCollection = $catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();
$catalogSearchModelCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);
$results = $catalogSearchModelCollection->getData();
```

What should I add to this to only find products with images?

Comment: I think the answer to your question can be found at [this other question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/42014/20131).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code for product which have images.

```
$catalogSearchModel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($q);
 $catalogSearchModelCollection = $catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();
 $catalogSearchModelCollection->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection');
 $catalogSearchModelCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);
 $results = $catalogSearchModelCollection->getData();
```